# Can't enable FTM, aka RTT function for Wi-Fi Location in RTL8812BU

Tags: wireless-networking

According to the Wi-Fi Alliance web page, [Realtek RTL8812BU](https://www.wi-fi.org/product-finder-results?keywords=WFA67454) is certified for Wi-Fi Location based on IEEE 802.11mc, FTM or RTT.

I've tested RTL8812BU with hostapd in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 and Raspberry Pi), however, I don’t know how to enable FTM response.

Could you let me know how to enable FTM function in RTL8812BU?

We've already tested Wi-Fi Location by Intel 8260 and Qualcomm IPQ 4018.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for [`hostap`](https://w1.fi/cvs.html) shows that these two options are available:

- `ftm_responder`
- `ftm_initiator`

So I assume you would have to set your config—which should be located in `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`—as follows:

```
ftm_responder=1
ftm_initiator=1
```

I assume you then have to restart the daemon—or reboot the machine—and you should be set. But this large—and very well commented—`hostapd.conf` states the following:

```
# Publish fine timing measurement (FTM) responder functionality
# This parameter only controls publishing via Extended Capabilities element.
# Actual functionality is managed outside hostapd.
#ftm_responder=0

# Publish fine timing measurement (FTM) initiator functionality
# This parameter only controls publishing via Extended Capabilities element.
# Actual functionality is managed outside hostapd.
#ftm_initiator=0
```

Not too sure what is meant by “This parameter only controls publishing via Extended Capabilities element.” but it seems like it’s worth testing it out.